# Question about pymodbusTCP server implementaion

Tags: tcp, server, modbus

We have a simulator(client) and controller(server).
The controller sends a command signal through ModbusTCP to the simulator. 
I want to emulate this controller on my computer.

**What I have done**

1. For the test, I wrote pymodbus Server script on my pc and pymodbus Client script on another PC. There was no problem to read holding and input register from client pc.
2. I connected my clinet pc to controller(server) to know what kind of values I have to send to actual client(simulator). **I found out that 8 registers(from 0 to 7) are used to store integer values.**
3. I tried to establish a connection between my pc(sever) and simulator computer(client).I was able to establish a connection and send a response to the client.

**Problem**

1. I have no information about this client(simulator) because we have no access to the client script.
2. I found out that this client sends a request not only for the reading but also for writing.
3. When I use the holding register, I got an error "illegal data address." But the input register does not show any error. For this reason, I am using input_register to save a specific integer number.
4. I stored some values on input_register, but sever input_registers are written by client(simulator) as below.

[write request from client(simulator)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19ySk.png)

[polling server(pc) with modpoll software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRL52.jpg)

**Question**

1. why write requests from the client(simulator) overwrite my input_register? As far as I know, input_register is used for only reading. I assume that I made a mistake in storing a variable on the input_register.
2. When I make a connection between controller and simulator, **wireshark and modpoll show that client(simulator) reads registers (from 0 to 7)**. But when I make a connection between my server(pc) and client(simulator), my sever response with different register numbers as below. Resister number starts from 1000. **Why does simulator request different register start number? ex) from 0: controller, from 1000: PC(sever)**

[First response from server(pc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcCBT.png)

3. Update! my server can respond with the values but with wrong register numbers. I changed starting register number(0 -->1000).
   I attached picture.

[response from server(pc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbeAS.png)

Please advice me on this issue. 
I will do my best effort to solve this issue.

'''

```
from pymodbus.server.sync import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext


from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock, ModbusSparseDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext

from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusBinaryFramer
#%%
import logging
FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s'
          ' %(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
#%%


#%%
def run_server():
    store = ModbusSlaveContext( 
    ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [28692,28692,28692,28692,28692,65508,65508,65508
    ]),zero_mode=True)
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
    StartTcpServer(context, address=("192.168.1.231", 502))

    identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
    identity.VendorName = 'Pymodbus'
    identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
    identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/'
    identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
    identity.ModelName = 'Pymodbus Server'
    identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.0'    

#%%
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

'''

Dear MarcosG, 
I attached screen-shots from wireshark as below.

[write request from clinet(simulator)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfX7Q.png)
- as you can see clinet(simulator) send a request for writing and register number start from 256.

[read response from server(controller)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9AX1.png)
- Sever(controller) responds to the request of clinet for reading. And it send a respond and register number start from 256.

[polling sever with modpoll software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOBE0.jpg)
- we can look the values on the registers of sever, as you can see, values are stored in the register from 0 to 7. These values are from controller lever. If I adjust lever, these values are changing.

[requested address_exel_File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncngA.png)
- We have one more simulator(bridge2). It shows the same register number with both controller(server) and pc(server).

problem: the actual registers of sever which store values are from 0 to 7. However, Client and server communicate with different registers (from 256) which contain "0" values. But there is no issue for adjusting parameters of ship on the simulator.

Best regards
Byeon Seongsu

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200633/discussion-on-question-by-seong-su-byeon-question-about-pymodbustcp-server-impl).